# importing TestHelper from braintree

Tags: python, braintree

I've been writing unit tests for my app, which uses [braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/) and [braintree_python](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_python) for billing. The module is installed using pip.

For some of my unit tests, I need to have a transaction's status transition from 'submitted_for_settlement' to 'settled', which, in the sandbox, takes too long for a quick unit test.

From the [Docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/python#settlement-status), and other Questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310096/braintree-why-braintree-transactions-created-via-api-or-via-sandbox-take-so/29311194), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868715/how-to-test-a-braintree-transaction-refund/27869383)), I gather this can be done using TestHelper.

Problem is, while TestHelper seems to exist in the [braintree/braintree_python](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_python/blob/master/tests/test_helper.py) repo, I cannot figure out how to import it.

Is there a way to import TestHelper and use it in my unit tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree.</sub>

You can use TestHelper, but instead I would suggest using the TestingGateway. Import it in your test file:

```
from braintree_python.braintree import TestingGateway
```

Initialize an instance of it with a gateway configured for use with your sandbox and call its methods on a sandbox transaction:

```
config = Configuration(braintree.Environment.Sandbox, "your_merchant_id", "your_public_key", "your_private_key")
braintree_gateway = BraintreeGateway(config)
testing_gateway = TestingGateway(braintree_gateway)

testing_gateway.settle_transaction("transaction_id")
```

Both these classes require API calls out to the Braintree sandbox, so this may be a better fit for your integration tests.

Comment: That seems to be working, thanks! Any reason the [docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/python#settlement-status) only mention TestHelper, and not this?

Comment: @Evan Giesel Glad you got it working! We're planning to update the docs to include this.